# CCCrypt crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, cryptography, exc-bad-access, commoncrypto, ecb

I am encrypting a video and sometimes I get a crash with CCCrypt.
This is my encryption method, can anyone shed any light on why it might crash? (The process is run in an NSOperation in a queue). The crash occurs on the `CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt` line

```
    char *key = MY_ENCRYPTION_KEY;
    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
    uint8_t encryptedData[dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    size_t encryptedLength;
    size_t encryptedDataLength = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode|kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, key, kCCKeySizeAES128, NULL, [data bytes], dataLength, encryptedData, encryptedDataLength, &encryptedLength);

    if(cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        NSData *output = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:encryptedData length:encryptedLength];

        completionBlock(nil, output);

    } else {
        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"Error encrypting" code:-999 userInfo:nil];
        completionBlock(error, nil);
    }
```

Comment: Eh, is your file over 4 GiB? You should really use `CCCryptorUpdate` and friends for large blocks of data. Otherwise you will have to read and write it all at once. ECB is insecure, use CBC with a random IV.

Comment: The data is only a couple of MB

Comment: It stops with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the CCCrypt line.

Comment: I've fixed this by changing the buffer `encryptedData` to `void * encryptedData = malloc(dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128);` I'd love to know why though.